# Metafont/Metapost — Find a path tangent through the external point

Tags: metapost, metafont, tangent

Assuming that I have the path `P` given, and let the `T` be a point outside the path `P`.
Is there an easy way to find the point `X` on the path `P` such that the tangent on point `X` going through the point `T`?

Example in Metapost:

```
outputformat := "svg";
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.svg";
beginfig(1)
pair T,X; path P;
T:=(800,900); P:=(0,0)..(300,100)..(200,600);
draw P withpen pencircle scaled 10;
draw T withpen pencircle scaled 20 withcolor red;
endfig; end
```

Basically, what I need is: `X = directionpoint (T-X) of P` (this is, of course, an error).

The only solution I can think of is to check an every point on the path until I found it, something like:

```
numeric v; v:=0;
forever: X:=point v of P;
exitif abs(angle(T-X) - angle(direction v of P)) < 0.001; % for example
v:=v+epsilon; endfor;
```

Of course, this specific code will not work in the every case. Plus, it's very slow.

Is there a better solution? Of course, in a general case it's possible that there is no the solution, or more than just one solution.

Comment: we can probably do it with the `solve` macro

Comment: The arc is a general path rather than the arc of a circle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
outputformat := "svg";
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.svg";
beginfig(1);
pair T,X; path P;
T:=(800,900); P:=(0,0)..(300,100)..(200,600);
draw P withpen pencircle scaled 10;
draw T withpen pencircle scaled 20 withcolor red;

vardef f(expr t) = angle direction t of P - angle (T - point t of P) < eps enddef;
X = point solve f (0, 2) of P;
draw X -- T withpen pencircle scaled 5 withcolor red;

endfig; end
```

which gets me this (although I was using eps as the output format and converting it to png to get this actual pic)

[image]

The `solve` macro is explained in [The Metafont Book](https://ctan.org/pkg/mfbook?lang=en) pp.176-177. Paraphrasing, the macro uses a binary search to find a numeric (brute force) solution to a non-linear equation.  You have to define a macro *with a single parameter* that returns either `true` or `false`.  You then pass the name of your macro to `solve` as a `suffix`, followed by a pair `(a, b)` such that `f(a)` is `true` and `f(b)` is `false`.  The `solve` macro returns a value between `a` and `b` that is "at the cutting edge between truth and falsity".

You can find the macro in your local copy of `plain.mp`:

```
vardef solve@#(expr true_x,false_x)= 
 tx_:=true_x; fx_:=false_x;
 forever: x_:=.5[tx_,fx_]; exitif abs(tx_-fx_)<=tolerance;
 if @#(x_): tx_ else: fx_ fi :=x_; endfor
 x_ enddef; % now x_ is near where @# changes from true to false
newinternal tolerance, tx_,fx_,x_; tolerance:=.01;
```

Notice how the passed macro is called with `@#(x_)`...

Comment: Great solution! Of course, it's not an universal solution, but for the my purposes it's absolutely perfect!